# E-customer behaviour in a Web application

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, analytics

I would like to know what are the main tools in the market for analysing/implementing E-customer behaviour in a Web application.

I just know Google Analytics which tracks client-side activity but maybe there are many alternatives using client and server-side scripts.

I already posted this question on webmasters.stackexchange.com [E-customer behaviour in a Web application](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31993/e-customer-behaviour-in-a-web-application), but it has been closed and cannot understand why!

Comment: E-customer behavior is a very broad term, and the question can't be answered wrong or right. This is a subjective question and thus not good for a QA site. You may have more luck at Quora.

Answer (score 8):

There are a vast array of tools to analyse user behaviour on a website. Ecommerce or otherwise.

### Google analytics has options like:

- [Ecommerce](http://cutroni.com/blog/2012/02/09/pimping-out-google-analytics-for-ecommerce-websites/)
- [Ecommerce custom variables](http://www.cardinalpath.com/advanced-google-analytics-e-commerce-tracking-just-in-time-for-the-holidays/)
- [Goals & Funnels](http://sixrevisions.com/tools/google-analytics-in-depth-goals-and-funnels/)
- [Goal flows](http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/10/19/path-analysis-in-google-analytics-with-flow-visualization/)

etc. which are useful in understanding things like drop off points, conversion rates, typical customer path and other shopper metrics.

### Other analytics packages useful for ecommerce / website behaviour:

- [Clicktale](http://clicktale.com)
- [Crazy egg](http://crazyegg.com)
- [Getclicky](http://getclicky.com)

and more. Some of these have a live / spy feature that allows you to see what users are doing realtime.

And the best way is to actually watch a recording of your users behaviour complete with keystrokes and mouse clicks / movements.

### User recording tools:

- [MouseStats](http://www.mousestats.com/)
- [Ghostrec](http://ghostrec.com)
- [Inspectlet](http://inspectlet.com)
- [Mouseflow](http://mouseflow.com)

Most of the above also do aggregated heatmaps and overlays to give you an insight into what users click most or what catches their eye etc.

### Incremental improvement to your website:

A/B testing or multi-variate testing are all the rage now. With A/B testing be aware of [local maximum](http://52weeksofux.com/post/694598769/the-local-maximum) and also avoid the [common mistakes](http://www.getelastic.com/5-common-ab-multivariate-testing-mistakes/) people make with testing. Google content expirements (formerly known as google website optimizer) now is part of Google Analytics and you can use this to do testing.

#### References / more reading for analysing and setting up ecommerce user behaviour:

- [Stalking Users](http://ui-patterns.com/blog/Stalk-your-users-Clicktale-userfly-and-mouseflow-review)
- [Driving online sales](http://www.slideshare.net/investni/driving-online-sales-craig-sullivan-22-march-2012)

Answer (score 3):

## Web Analytics Solution

First of all you need to choose a general propose Web Analytics Solution. Since you are an E-commerce you want to choose one that has good support for tracking E-commerce data.

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) is the obvious choice here not only because it's free but also because it's better documented and easier to implement.

depending on your size it may make sense to implement a more Enterprise level Ecommerce solution. You may want to take a look at [Adobe Omniture](http://www.omniture.com/) and [IBM CoreMetrics](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/marketing-solutions/coremetrics/). They are much more expensive not only because of the licenses but on an implementation perspective. It may take months to implement one of these other tools and the cost of the implementation can be almost the same as the costs for the licenses. Still if you need more enterprise level analysis and integrations with other BI solutions it may be worth taking a look at these.

Note that Google Analytics also has a [Premium Edition](http://www.google.com/analytics/premium/). This is a fairly new alternative and provide some extra features and early access to beta features.

## Product Recommendation

Depending on your Ecommerce platform you might already have some kind of product recommendation or up-selling. You usually can improve these systems based on analytics data. There are just a few options on the market, and most companies doing this tend to develop their own recommendation engine.

If you're just getting started with it, it might be worth looking at [LiftSuggest](http://www.liftsuggest.com/). I haven't tried it but they seem easy enough to implement and leverage Google Analytics data to improve cross-selling.

## HeatMap

It's easy enough to implement and may provide some nice isights. I find them more distracting usually but every now and then you can make good use of them. The most common seen around are [CrazyEgg](http://www.crazyegg.com/) and [ClickTale](http://www.clicktale.com/).

## Behavioral Targeting

This is a technique to customize your site based on a previous knowledge you have about the visitor in order to increase his conversion rate. Tools don't help you much here, since you have to customize your site and no tool can predict how to do that. One common approach is to create buckets depending on factors that you can infer. For example: Users with Internet Explorer might be less tech savvy and thus might be more interested in non-tech products. On the other side Linux users are probably on the technology field. So you can put users on buckets depending on which country they came from, which browser they're using or if they are logged in you can use the information they entered on their profile or based on previous purchases. One tool that helps you doing that is called [BTBuckets](http://btbuckets.com/).

## A/B and Multivariate Testing

Google analytics has an A/B testing tool integrated with the tool. Another Good tool that provides both A/B and Multivariate testing are [Unbounce](http://unbounce.com/), [Optimizely](https://www.optimizely.com/) and [Webtrends Optimize](http://webtrends.com/products/optimize/).

## Custom Solution

Everybody these days are developing custom solutions. If you still have money and time to spend on Web Analytics after you exausted the other options you can look into building your own. Collecting the data the way you want and analyzing the granular data. Here solutions range fro server side to client side collection, but for the analysis they are usually done with [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) or with a OLAP Business Intelligence Tool like [Microstrategy](http://www.microstrategy.com/).

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a called [Customer Relationship Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management) software, or **CRM**.  They vary greatly, so without an in-depth understanding of your exact needs it's impossible to recommend specific ones.  Any good CRM will let you analyze your site visitors in various ways.  For example, you can see if customers bought *X*, they often came back and bought *Y* one month later.

The difficult part is integration because these systems need information about orders and other user actions.  If you're using an off-the-shelf e-commerce package, there are often CRM options readily available.

For a "lighter" system you can use Google Analytics or similar, since it lets you send tracking, conversion, and sales information from the browser.  It's great for analyzing the overall success of the site and tracking user actions across pages, but less powerful for sales-specific reporting and analysis.